# Google Sheets IMPORTXML, text ONLY for xpath with text inside <a href> tags

Tags: google-sheets, text, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import just the text from a div on a client's site into a Google sheets using the =IMPORTXML function so they can see everything on one sheet. The problem is that some pages have href tags wrapped around text, which if using `=IMPORTXML(website, "[xpath]/text")` gives me an error about the array overwriting the next cell. So I tried some of the tricks around the web (wrapping in `=REGEXREPLACE`, =JOIN, etc) and those got me the text of the div minus the text of the children.

For example, if I have this HTML

```
<div class="text">
I want to get this text and
<a href="http some link">this text, too</a>
so what do I do?
</div>
```

In my sheet I get `"I want to get this text and    so what do I do?"`

Comment: Please, Share you example, take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I figured I'd get a response like this. Unfortunately, the data is on a private page so I can't share it.

Comment: What is the [xpath]/text? and what the desired output you need?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for anyone else trying to do this:

```
=JOIN(CHAR(10),IMPORTXML("site","//div[@class='divclass']//text()"))
```

My mistake was using `/text()` instead of `//text()` The extra / was missing.